# Glob pattern in Azure Pipelines to exclude map files and asset folder

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, glob, azure-pipelines-tasks

I'm trying to use an "Amazon S3 Upload" task in Azure Pipelines to upload all my website files except anything in my "assets" folder and except my JS map files. The glob pattern I tried using is

```
**/!(assets|*.map)
```

But my assets folder is still being uploaded. I think glob patterns must work differently in Azure, because an online glob tester showed this would work. What is the correct syntax for excluding a folder and a file type using an Azure task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the correct syntax for excluding a folder and a file type using an Azure task?

As the state of that option:

[image]

This option supports **Supports multiple lines of minimatch patterns**.

There is a list of file [matching patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns) you can use and [some most important rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201825/tfs-drop-exclude-obj-folder-using-minimatch-pattern/45185088#45185088).

So, you can try to use following patterns:

```
**
!**/assets/**
!**/*.map
```

Hope ths helps.

Comment: I think that worked. I tried this approach before, but was missing the `**` line. Thanks.