# Where is TfvcTemplate.12.xaml build configuration

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild, c#-6.0

I have TFS 2013 Update 3 installed and Visual Studio 2015. I want to write code with C#6, but it won't build in TFS server because it still uses VS2013 builder. So I installed VS 2015 on my TFS server (build controller is also installed on that machine). Still no luck. I was googling around how to fix it, but solutions I found online doesn't seem to work. 
I tried editing the MS Build Arguments to `/tv:14.0 /p:GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile=false /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0` and that didn't fix it either.
One place says if I have **`DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml`** then it won't work. It says I need to have **`TfvcTemplate.12.xaml`**. [[source]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659106/tfs-2013-building-net-4-6-c-sharp-6-0?rq=1)

So, my problem is I can't find the **`TfvcTemplate.12.xaml`**. Does anybody has any idea where can I find that file or how to configure the TFS 2013 to build using msbuild 14.0?

Comment: Your problem is how to use a 2015 build environment in TFS 2013, not the location of some template. There are various answers to this , eg [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601047/running-tfs-build-with-c-sharp-6-0-features) - you don't need to install VS 2015, you need to install the MS Build 2015 Tools and then modify the template [as shown in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659106/tfs-2013-building-net-4-6-c-sharp-6-0?rq=1)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have installed the MSBuild 2015 Tools already and followed the exact steps shown in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659106/tfs-2013-building-net-4-6-c-sharp-6-0?rq=1. Also that post says that having DefaultTemplate.11.xaml doesn't work which is what I have

Answer (score 1):

The TfvsTemplate.12.xaml build template can be found on the build definition. Go to Process tab then select TfvsTemplate.12.xaml in the Build process template section. Then you click on Download link and you can customize it.

Comment: I tried it already. There is no TfvsTemplate.12.xaml in that list.

Comment: Could you please download it and post it on the web somewhere, where I can download it?