# Compilation Error when building on TFS agent but not on my local machine

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tfs

I am new to working with TFS Builds and for the life of me cannot figure out why I am getting a compilation error on TFS when it builds fine locally.

[image: this is the error message from TFS Build]

Line 98 is:
[image]

Both my workstation and the workstation where the builds are run have the same .NET frameworks. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I may be wrong, but it seems that TFS build uses compiler version that doesn't understand expression-bodied members. And as it is a language feature, it is not (mostly) dependent on .NET version, so project level .NET version settings won't help to solve it.

Comment: The version of `MsBuild` being called may be different between what you're developing on and what your build server is being told to build on. It's hard to tell with the information you provided.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running TFS Build with C# 6.0 features](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601047/running-tfs-build-with-c-sharp-6-0-features)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure the build successful, you should **keep your build server environment the same with your local environment.** Please double check this, such as .Net version.

And if you are tfs2013 building the app, please follow below :

> You can either install the ["Microsoft Build Tools 2015"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) on the
>   build agent machine and configure the build template to use that
>   version of msbuild, or else install the Microsoft.Net.Compilers NuGet
>   package in the projects you want to build with the new compiler.
>
> Source Link:
>   [Running TFS Build with C# 6.0 features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601047/running-tfs-build-with-c-sharp-6-0-features)

Comment: Thanks for the  reply, can you please provide an example of where in the build template I can make the configuration change? I am using XAML Build Definitions within Visual Studio 2015 and don't see an option to set that.

Comment: The Build Tools did the trick! Thank you. I apologize for the delay in accepting your answer, I got caught up on project work and this had to be put on the back burner.